# Domain routes in laravel

Tags: laravel, deployment, azure-web-app-service, devops

I have a laravel appplication running with apache on azure app services and everything is all right, but press click in any link its redirects me to the app service domain for example:

> [myapp.azurewebsites.net](http://myapp.azurewebsites.net)

but me domain is for example:

> [myapp.com](http://myapp.com)

I dont know if i should change the .htaccess file, or the webconfig file, or some laravel configuration?

Comment: What is the value of `APP_URL` in your `.env`?

Comment: In APP_URL the value is: myapp.com

Comment: Can you share a blade view so we can see how are you forming the URL?

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know if i should change the .htaccess file, or the webconfig file, or some laravel configuration?

- In your site's web.config file, you need to add a redirect rule from your ***wwwroot*** folder or if you don't have a web.config file, then you can create one and just paste the below text by changing host names:

```html
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>  
        <rules>  
          <rule name="Redirect requests to default azure websites domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />  
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yoursite\.azurewebsites\.net$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yoursite.com/{R:0}" />  
          </rule>  
        </rules>  
    </rewrite>  
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

- Please refer  [REDIRECT TO SITE USING A .HTACCESS FILE?](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/all/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-.htaccess-file) in order to make changes in redirect URLs of .htaccess file.
- To make changes in the routing of laravel configuration, please refer [HTTP Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing).